# Will kronecker product and usual matrix addition form semiring on the set of matrices?

Tags: matrices, semiring

Suppose $(S, +, \otimes, \rm 0, [1])$ is an algebraic structure, where $S$ is the set of matrices of any orders, $+$ is usual addition of matrix, $\otimes$ is Kronecker product, $\rm 0$ is zero matrix (dimension not defined) and $[1]$ is $1×1$ matrix with the only entry is $1$. Then  $(S, +, \otimes, \rm 0, [1])$  seems to be a semiring because it satisfies all the axioms of a semiring except the absorption law, i.e., $x.0=0~\forall ~x\in S$, where $0$ on R.H.S is of higher dimension than that of L.H.S.

My goal left here is to show that zero matrices on L.H.S and R.H.S are both same or equivalent and if so I might be done.

So, could we show these two zero matrices equivalent or the same?

Comment: Downvoting as the question is vague. What is the equivalence and what is the " given context". Please be more specific. But I am not hopeful of a relation connecting matrices of different sizes. I guess any such relation would not be defined algebraically and may not be  worth studying.

Comment: Obviously you can make up equivalence relations.  Say that two matrices are equivalent if the sums of their elements are equal, or if their maximum elements are equal, and so on.  Two matrices of different shapes can be equivalent under these definitions.  The real questions is, are there any useful equivalence relations on matrices of different shapes, and I can only say I've never heard of any.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions..let me edit my question and repost it

Comment: Imbed finite matrices of any size in infinite matrices of finite rank by appending zeroes.  Call two matrices equivalent if they are equal as infinite matrices.

Comment: @fredgoodman The Kronecker product of two such things would be... interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Your structure fails to be a semiring, because $+$ is not a total operation; e.g. you can't add a $2 \times 7$ to a $4 \times 4$ matrix. Did you mean the direct sum $\oplus$ instead? I.e. the direct sum of two such matrices would be a $6 \times 11$ matrix whose top-left corner contains the first matrix, whose bottom-right corner contains the second matrix, and whose remaining entries are zero.

But regarding the question you're asking, I think the idea you're missing is that the dimensions of a matrix are $m \times n$ where $m$ and $n$ can be any natural number: in particular, they can be *zero*.

The thing you want $0$ to be, I think, is the matrix of dimension $0 \times 0$. This matrix satisfies $0 \otimes x = 0 = x \otimes 0$ for every matrix $x$.

Comment: As an aside, working with zero dimensions takes a little bit of care; e.g. when you get the definition right, the $0 \times 0$ matrix is both a zero matrix and an identity matrix, and its determinant is actually $1$.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.  I had really missed  the concept of total operation for being closed.